# I lost my data on iPad 2

Tags: ios, software-update, ipad, data-recovery

I updated my iPad 2 to iOS 7. It blocked and asked me to plug it to iTunes. I did connect it to computer then I was asked to restore the iPad. I am afraid I lost all my data and I don't have the access now to syncronise it to computer.

Is there any way how to recover my data from iPad updated before restoring it?

Comment: There are dozens of questions here covering the basics. If you want to edit in some details to make this unique, that would trigger a review, but it's likely we have coverage for this already on the site.

Answer (score 0):

How about using iCloud? Backup everything before you start restoring. http://www.icloud.com

Another Way how to Backup iPad 2 : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4542101

Hope this will help you.